# Daniel Craig's accent in Knives Out trailer (Southern, RP, different?)

Tags: pronunciation, accent

What is his accent in this trailer?

https://youtu.be/sL-9Khv7wa4?t=71

https://youtu.be/sL-9Khv7wa4?t=86

Would you call it Southern? I'd say it's a mix of RP and Southern at best. He seems to have retained many typical British features, yet I'm no expert when it comes to American accents.

Supposedly he based his accent on Shelby Foote, but they don't appear all that similar. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZC3gwUOz54

Comment: I noticed this too.  He was inconsistent.  I think he tried to fake a mild Southern accent, but he slipped back into his accustomed British one at times.

Comment: I would call this accent "Col. Sanders wannabe" ... a.k.a. "Looney Tunes [Foghorn Leghorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foghorn_Leghorn)."

Comment: If you want to see an English actor doing a convincing American dialect, see Idris Elba playing Stringer Bell in *The Wire*.

Comment: @Robusto Wow, I didn't even stop for a moment to consider whether his accent was fake or not when I watched the series.

Comment: [Daniel Craig Explains Why His Knives Out Character Has A Southern Accent](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2485851/daniel-craig-explains-why-his-knives-out-character-has-a-southern-accent)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is whether he actually _has_ a Southern accent or is it RP jumbled up with Southern judging by the few lines he manages to say in the trailer :) (timestamps given)

Comment: Erm... Daniel Craig is ***British***, with a finely-honed BrE RP accent. I didn't bother to *read* that link, but obviously any "fake accent" in a movie role depends on his ability as an actor (and whether or not he and the director have any interest in "authenticity", which isn't usually the case). Most actors fake accents sound pretty crappy to those who actually *speak* the specific dialect being attempted.

Comment: I did bother to read the linked article (it didn't help) even before posting the question, which is whether he actually _has_ a Southern accent or is it RP jumbled up with Southern judging by the few lines he manages to say in the trailer :) (timestamps given) I'm terribly sorry if I misled you by saying "he" - I obviously meant the character. I thought that by saying he retained some British features I made it clear that I do realise he (Daniel Craig, not the character) is British.

Comment: I'll note that I saw the movie & never looked at the trailers.  As I said, I noticed his mild Southern accent, but his British accent broke through several times.  It was not distracting, though -- more a part of the charm of the movie.

Comment: I'll also note that I finally, just today, got around to reading the New Yorker review of the movie, and they state that a Southern accent was the intent of the producers.